# 'All Time' reputation rank shown in percent

Tags: support, users

Is it possible to see  *All Time* reputation rank shown in percent? If you i.e. have *top 10% this month* shown on your user page - you can get the *All Time* rank in number i.e. #12345 - can this be shown as i.e. *top 15% all time*?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries - I think this might be what you are looking for: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile

Comment: Thanks @Marco13, I didn't know of the *SO queries* - very useful

Comment: that query is wrong - its cut-off is at 100 rep, and for some reason the rank it finds is (for me) about 20 lower (i.e. better) than what's shown in the "leagues" ranking. It might be counting duplicate rep entries as one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Lo, there be a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/6485/show-each-users-percentile-in-rep-leagues) for yea this very reason.

Answer (score 13):

when you click on "top 10% this month", you get thrown into something like `http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2015-10-01/...`; in the address bar, double click on "month" (it gets selected), type over "alltime", and press Enter.

you will see your alltime rank. then look at the side table and note "total reputation" entry for "200+".

divide the first number by the second, and multiply by 100, to get your "top X% overall" percentile, as would be shown by SO.